# Excel - How to copy rows and discard others based on today's date?

Tags: excel, duplicates, filtering, vba

I have a worksheet, and in one sheet called Payments, every row, on column A has a date in ascending order, on column C there's a client name, on column E there's a monetary value and on column G there's a Yes/No Checkbox.

The Dates sometimes repeat themselves, but the other values, do not (the Y/N/ Checkbox also repeat themselves). So, sometimes i have:

m / d / y

02/02/2014 - Client X - 100,00 - y;

02/02/2014 - Client Z - 120,00 - n;

02/**03**/2014 - Client W - 110,00 - n;

etc.

What I need is this: on another sheet called Today's Dues, in the same worksheet, when colum A from Payments sheet (the date column) is today's date, the entire row from that column from A to G) is copied to Todays Due sheet. And the same would apply to all the other rows where the A column had todays date. But, tomorrow, that sheet would need to update itself, so the information from yesterday would not be there anymore, just the new rows with the new day's date.

Since there is no more than 10 payments a day, the space available on Todays Due would not need to be bigger than 10 rows, but would have to get information from the entire A column of Payments sheet.

What is was thinking was to create a Macro that would duplicate ALL data from Payments sheet, then automatically apply a filter with todays date. This Macro would be the first thing happening on opening. But this has been proving to be very frustrating. I cant seem to make Excel recognize my dates as dates, only as text, i tried everything.

Any help, or a more elegant solution, please ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming multiple rows of same date are in order, these should work.

Date:
`=IF(INDEX(Payments!A:A,MATCH(TODAY(),Payments!A:A,0)+ROW()-2)=0,"",INDEX(Payments!A:A,MATCH(TODAY(),Payments!A:A,0)+ROW()-2))`

Client Name:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Payments!$C:$C,MATCH($A2,Payments!$A:$A,0)+ROW()-2),"")`

Value:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Payments!$E:$E,MATCH($A2,Payments!$A:$A,0)+ROW()-2),"")`

Yes/No:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Payments!$G:$G,MATCH($A2,Payments!$A:$A,0)+ROW()-2),"")`

Put each formula in consecutive columns to get your 4 unique values.  Drag these down for 10 rows to collect all possible values.

**Note:  The 2 in "ROW()-2" will be whatever row number you start this on.  I used 2 since I put headers in the first row.